# How to send a email using outlook and chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, email, outlook

I want to use chrome extension to open a new window of outlook email which has a specific content and include attachments and all recipient email addresses, while I am logging in the outlook. Is it possible? Because I have no idea, how can I do that?  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. To automate the desktop edition of Outlook you need to use the CO automation technology which is not supported in Chrome. You can automate the desktop editions of Outlook from Internet Explorer only. Other browsers are not aware of the COM automation technology (of course, on Windows only). If we speak about opening a web page with O365 mailbox - the best what you could do is to navigate to a specific URL.

As a possible workaround you may consider using the [mailto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa767737(v=vs.85)) protocol which allows to open a client's e-mail system and begins a new email message. For example:

```
<a href="mailto:user@example.com?
    subject=MessageTitle&amp;
    body=Message Content">
    Contact Us</a>
```

Or in the HTML form:

```
<form action="mailto:user@example.com" method="get">
<input name="subject" type="hidden" value="Message Title">

Feedback:<br/>
<textarea name=body cols="40">
Please share your thoughts here
and then choose Send Feedback.
</textarea>

<input type="submit" value="Send Feedback">
</form>
```

Comment: I am not using Desktop edition of outlook. I want to use the web 
 link "https://outlook.office.com/mail/". But I want to open a new web page of outlook that is  composing a new message using chrome edition. I want the draft of email that can already include the specific attachment and the contents. For more details, I want to input a folder link in the chrome extension, then the draft can include all the txt files inside that folder. I want to confirm the message before I send it out. The above suggestion cannot achieve my purpose. Is my wish possible? How can I do that?